# Delete a row with the highest value of a specific column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I want to delete the row with the highest value on specific column

(I know that there are answers for that but none of them work for me for some reason)

All the coding I do in visual studio c# with SQL

MyDatabase: hours

```
Hours_Left | Hours_Spent | Time_Written | Mode | Time_Start | Time_End | Index
==============================================================================
aa         | bb          | cc           | dd   | ee         | ff       | 3
gg         | hh          | ii           | jj   | kk         | ll       | 4
mm         | nn          | oo           | pp   | qq         | rr       | 5
ss         | tt          | uu           | vv   | ww         | xx       | 6

[Hours_Left]   VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Hours_Spent]  VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Time_Written] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Mode]         VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Time_Start]   VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Time_End]     VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Index]        INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL
```

My Code:

```
if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Open();
        }
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = @"DELETE FROM hours WHERE Index = select max(Index) from hours limit 1";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Display_Data();
```

Don't work either when `commandText` is

```
@"DELETE TOP(1) FROM hours
  WHERE Index in 
  (SELECT TOP(1) Index FROM hours
  ORDER BY Index DESC);";
```

I want to delete the whole row of the highest index - i.e delete the row with the index 6 that it is the highest index

Error at:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The error is:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'Index'. If
>   this is intended as a part of a table hint, A WITH keyword and
>   parenthesis are now required. See SQL Server Books Online for proper
>   syntax.

Comment: `DELETE FROM hours WHERE [Index] IN (select max([Index]) from hours)`

Comment: Its common to name indexes like `%TableName%Id`. In your case it would be `HourId`. Thus you would avoid such issues in future.

Comment: Not question related, but why are all the other columns varchar(max)?

Comment: @MadMyche I don't know, I needed a string but text made problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Index is a keyword, you need to use `[Index]`.

Comment: Plus one from me. First real attempt to find the root cause of problem instead of telling other ways to achieve the goal.

Comment: +1  Could you also use an alias and qualify the columnname?  Would that work - or are the brackets necessary, regardless?

Comment: You'd need a CTE or a sub select to use a column alias, and the brackets would be still be required when initial referring to the column anyway. I'd argue that the column should probably actually be called Id anyway which would remove the issue entirely.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
 delete from hours where Index = max(index);
```

Comment: This will also fail like OP's.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by "ajg", Problem in second query is usage of reserved keyword `Index` use square bracket to escape the keyword

Better way to do this is using `CTE`

```
;with cte as
(
select top (1) * from hours order by [Index] desc
)
delete from cte
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
delete x
from dbo.[Hours] x
where exists(select 1 from dbo.[Hours] xx having MAX(xx.[Index])=x.[Index])
```

Comment: Nikhil Agrawal is correct. [Index] needed. Above example is incorrect as I was missing it

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can do:

```
DELETE h
    FROM hours h
    WHERE h.Index = (select max(h2.Index) from hours h2) ;
```

If you are concerned that `index` could have duplicates, then use `delete` with `top`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  delete from hours where [Index] = (select max([Index]) from hours)
```

i guess you are missing brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
 delete from tablename 
 where columnname = 
 ( select dummytable.maxVal from 
    (select max(columnname) as maxVal from tablename) 
   dummytable
 );
```